# javascript changes to rails input tag are not saved when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack

I'm updating a rails 5 app to rails 6. In the updating process, I'm realized that I have a form bug in my rails 5 app that continues on the rails 6 version.
The problem is the following, the view has a form with several input text tags (one for each attribute defined in my model Feature). One input tag is a dropdown menu that controls which input tags are enabled and which not. This is managed with an on change listener. This listener includes code that clears the disabled fields. The logic is the following:

- The user selects option A, then the input text tag "attr_two" must be cleaned and disabled
- The user selects option B, then the input text tag "attr_one" must be cleaned and disabled.

The field is cleaned setting the value attribute to "" with jquery val("") function  or the plain accession .value = "" (I'm tested both ways). The problem is that in the view all works perfectly, the fields are cleared and disabled but when I inspect the data saved for the model in the database are the old ones instead to be "". So when the user wants to edit a Feature the fields are mixed as following:

- Field1: Z and Field2: Y

But the desired behavior would be:

- Field1: Z and Field2: ""
- Field1: "" and Field2: Y

I cannot understand why the JavaScript modifications on the input text tags are not passed to the rails controller and the old values are the same instead "".

Comment: Add relevant parts of your html and js code to the question. I suspect you're using some UI tool that creates a "magic" field that looks like an input but is not an actual input and updates the actual hidden input in the background. If you update the value of it with js, it may not fire the callbacks needed for it to function.

Comment: I just noticed you say you disable the fields. Is that really what you meant? If you do, then disabled fields are not sent to the server (no matter their value) and rails does not update their value. Check the server logs to see what the server actually receives (is it "Field1=Z&Field2=Y" or just "Field2=Y"

Comment: @SiimLiiser hit the key point in the last comment. I have disabled the fields and it caused the described problems. I changed to readonly attribute and I have the desired behavior in my rails form.

Comment: I posted it also as an answer, so it's easier to see for anyone stumbling on this question. Please accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable fields in html, then they're not sent to the server when the form is submitted regardless of their value. Once rails receives the the request, a parameter being missing is interpreted as "no change".

You should change the fields to read-only instead of disabled so that they still look disabled to the user, but are sent to the server to be updated to empty.

A safer option would be to have logic enforcing this on the backend. If one of the fields is received, update the other to empty or check which one should be empty depending on the value of your select.

However, a front-end solution should be good enough for a prototype.